How can I change the color of the "text" cursor in VS Code in my VDI?
I have a project I have to work on using a VDI (Virtual Desktop Infrastructure). The OS of the VDI is Windows 10. For some odd reason, the "text" cursor (the line cursor that appears when you hover the cursor over text) is black in VS Code, and since I'm using the dark mode theme it makes it difficult to see the cursor. However, the text cursor is white when I'm in VS Code (and in dark mode) on my local computer (OS: Windows 11), and black on other web pages.
I don't want to change the theme color of the background in VS Code, only the text cursor. And I only want it to be white for VS Code.
I have tried reading forums and watched explanation videos, but could only find information about how to change the normal cursor, how to change the color of the highlight color when you highlight text, or how to edit the color of the text edit blinker (the line that indicates where you are when you are typing).
I was expecting to only change the text cursor to white over my dark background theme in VS Code in my VDI.
